# How to plot vector function r(t) = i + j + t*k

Tags: plotting, vector

How can I plot the vector function $r(t) = i + j + t\;k$, where *i, j, k* are unit vectors, and *t* is the parameter of the function r.

Comment: you want the vector field or just the vector bundle?

Comment: belisarus answered my question. thank you.

Comment: And you really couldn't find this in the documentation?

Comment: @MathStudent you are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1, 1, t}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, belisarius. you saved my life.

Comment: @MathStudent No, I just answered a very simple question. I suggest you to read a few coding examples in the Help system.

Comment: ... if you want to live safe

Comment: Hmm... That's not really the graph of the requested function but rather the image of the function (over an interval of the domain, of course). To plot the actual function would be to plot a function from (some subinterval) of the reals R to 3-space [latex]R^3[/latex], and that would require working in 4-space; or it would require creating an animation or dynamic display in which the domain is represented by time.

Comment: @murray Yep, but it is the only thing that I was able to produce in **R**^3

Comment: As I suggested, use time as an additional dimension:
`Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{1,1,s},{s,0,t},PlotRange->{{0,2},{0,2},{0,2}}],{{t,0.001},0.001,2}]`

Comment: @murray Ok. But that isn't what I call a Plot. Don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though belisarius has answered the question to OP's satisfaction, I figured I'd throw this in there in case someone came to this question looking to plot a vector field in three dimensions like murray suggested.

```
Animate[        
   VectorPlot3D[{1, 1, t}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},          
   VectorScale -> Medium, RegionFunction -> ((#1 #2 #3 > 0) &)],      
{t, 0, 2}]
```

Information about the options I applied (to make the plot look a bit easier to understand) is in the documentation for `VectorPlot3D`.